# 1-form on variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and consider the affine curve $Z(-y^5+x^4-1) \subset \mathbb{A}^2(k)$. Define on it the rational 1-form $w=\frac{dx}{5y^4}=\frac{dy}{4x^3}$. Is there a (relatively straightforward) way to see that $w$ has no poles on the curve $\textit{without}$ calculating its order at all points?

Comment: Clearly this form has no poles when $x \neq 0$ and when $y \neq 0$. Moreover, $(0,0)$ is not on your curve so you can conclude that there is no poles.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nicolas. What makes you say without any calculation that surely when say x is not zero, it doesn't have a pole?

Comment: Because if $z$ is some coordinate on a curve, the poles of $\frac{f}{g}dz$ are by definition the zeroes of $g$. In your case, since $\omega$ can be written as $\frac{dy}{4x^3}$ this shows that if $x \neq 0$ there is no poles.